# How Do I Count Users Per Group with MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by, subquery

I have a table of groups:

- id -- a unique ID (primary key)
- group -- a group name

I have a table of users:

- username -- a unique string (primary key)
- group_id -- a foreign key link to group.id

In this case, a user is only going to be in one single group. So, in MySQL, how do I list out groups and their count of member users?

I tried using a subselect and count, but it ends up showing the same count on all groups.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
SELECT group.id,COUNT(users.username) FROM groups
INNER JOIN users ON users.group_id=groups.id
GROUP BY groups.id
```

You can use a LEFT JOIN instead if you want to display empty groups per @Michael's comment

Comment: +1, except for you may want the `LEFT JOIN` to account for empty groups.

Comment: And the alias u isn't defined (or needed)

Comment: I guess that is what happens when you try to change the way you write a query for simplicity sake ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
select g.group, count(*) as group_count
from groups g, users g
where g.id=u.group_id
group by g.groupname
```